# typing: TypeVar vs. Union, mypy error: Missing type parameters for generic type

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm struggling to understand when to use TypeVar and when to use Union despite spending a significant amount of time in the [typing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and [PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/).

Simple version of the question: what's the difference between `Numeric = TypeVar('Numeric', int, float)` and `Numeric = Union[int, float]`?

Here's a more detailed example of what I'm running into:

```py
"""example1.py
Use of Union to define "Numeric" type.
"""

from typing import Union, Sequence

Numeric = Union[int, float]

Vector = Sequence[Numeric]

Matrix = Sequence[Vector]
```

Check with mypy:

```
$ mypy --strict example1.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Use `TypeVar` instead:

```py
"""example2.py
Use of TypeVar to define "Numeric" type.
"""

from typing import TypeVar, Sequence

Numeric = TypeVar('Numeric', int, float)

Vector = Sequence[Numeric]

Matrix = Sequence[Vector]
```

Check with mypy:

```
$ mypy --strict example2.py
example2.py:11: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Vector"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The above `mypy` error is referring to the definition of `Matrix`. Why is `mypy` happy with `example1.py` but not `example2.py`?

I'm able to eliminate the error in `example2.py` by changing the last line to `Matrix = Sequence[Vector[Numeric]]`.

Version information:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.8.4
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.782
```

Comment: I am not sure about the error itself. In general, the `TypeVar` is a placeholder for exactly one of `int` or `float`, but the choice won't be fixed until you actually provide a value based on it. That is, `Matrix` can contain all `int` values, or all `float` values, but not a mixture of each. With `Union`, each element of an individual `Matrix` could be an `int` or `float` independent of the type of the other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeVar` is for creating generic types.

```
Numeric = TypeVar('Numeric', int, float)

Vector = Sequence[Numeric]
```

... means `Vector[T]` is an alias for `Sequence[T]` with the constraint that `issubclass(T, (int, float))`. This means mypy considers `Vector` to be an incomplete type, it asks: "a Vector of what?", and you can write `Vector[Numeric]` to mean: "a Vector of any Numeric".

It's often used for functions or classes, like this:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V')
def map(f: Callable[[T], V], it: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[V]:
    for x in it:
        yield f(x)
```

This means you can make things type-safe even if you don't know exactly what types you're gonna get.

Comment: While `TypeVar` and `Union` have different use cases, this answer doesn't explain why `example2.py` could be fixed in the way it was.

Comment: I guess I should have made that more explicit, yes. Do you think my edit properly explains it?

Comment: OK, yeah. I think my confusion was in thinking of `Sequence` as being simpler than it really is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't understand why declaring `Vector = Sequence[Numeric]` leads to an "incomplete type" seeing as I've specified it should be a sequence of numerics. My (perhaps naive) objective is to define `Vector` as any sequence consisting of `int`s and/or `float`s. And I'd like `Matrix` to simply be a sequence of `Vector`s. Finally, I'd like to annotate functions like `def dot_product(v1: Vector, v2: Vector)`. Then, in `dot_product` I know that each element of `v1` and `v2` are either `int`s or `float`s. For this use case would I use `Union` to define `Numeric`?

Comment: Yes, you would use `Union` for that. `TypeVar` is for _generic_ types, for when you want to use it like `Vector[T]`, I'm not sure how to explain it any clearer than that.

Comment: Thanks, Jasmijn. I appreciate your assistance, and will continue reading the docs and examples (and re-reading your answer + commnets) to get a better understanding of the application of generic types.